# Magento downloadable product dynamic link after successful order

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have a downloadable product let's say it is business card template in which customer has to enter their name, logo and address as input. After placing the order i will create the business card with the input details and create a new business card. Now after successful order and payment i want the customer to download the newly created business card with the details in it. So i want to change the downloadable product url for each order which is different from the one in the admin end.

Any help or idea on how to achieve this will be more appreciated.

I have searched for this and found no relevant answers hence creating this thread.

Comment: A potential solution - add a new field to the order_items table that allows you to manipulate an additional URL to download the product from.  Add this to the admin system so that you can update it when you complete the order?

Comment: Yes thats a good idea, no need to update the url from admin end because the url will be auto generated. But i have to place this url in the customer downloadable product page rite

Comment: Yes - you can do this with a custom block.